# csv parsing into specific format with python

Tags: python, csv

I need your help about a school project that I'm currently working on. 
So I have a CSV file with the following headers: 
first_name, last_name, Email, Position

And i'd like to have as an outpout an array of this specific format:

```
users [ User(first_name='data row1', last_name='data row1', email='data row1', position=data row1), User(first_name='data row2', last_name='data row2', email='data row2', position=data row2), etc ...]
```

If you want more context, i'm working on Gophish (https://github.com/gophish/gophish) and i'm trying to automate the group creation via the python api client (https://gophish.gitbooks.io/python-api-client/content/groups.html)

Thanks for your time !

--
Robin

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have already tried some solutions like the csv module of python, especially the function "DictReader" which gives me a data that approximates the one I want and then trying to replace the characters I did not want (for example { -> ()
Using this technique I found myself stuck because there are characters I needed in some places

i'll try to look in @maiky_forrester solution and give some update if i need more help !

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link.

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

something like this:

```
import csv

ifile  = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

for row in reader:
  #CREATE USER OR ADD IT TO YOUR ARRAY
  #User(first_name='row[0]', last_name='row[1]', email='row[2]', position=row[3])
  #[..]
ifile.close()
```

Comment: Hey,

thanks for the help ! i was already looking on this site but i started to play with the "DictReader" function. I was apparently fllowing the wrong way ;)

thanks to your comment , I came up with:

for row in cr:
        print "User(", "first_name=","'",row[0],"'",",","last_name=","'",row[1],"'",",","email=","'",row[2],"'",",","position=","'",row[3],"'",")",","

it's looks kinda dirty but it gets the job done..
Now I just need to find about how can i put each of theses strings into my array :)